# How to use Q_ENUMS in PyQt

Tags: python, enums, properties, pyqt, qt-designer

I am creating a custom widget that inherits from `QLabel`, and I would like to have a property on my widget to represent how the data must be formatted when presenting to the user.

For that I am trying to use `Q_ENUMS`, but I'm not having much success. I can get the property to show in Designer, but the UI file saved shows the enum as `PyDMLabel::STRING` and not as I would expect `DisplayFormat::STRING`.

Here is my code for the widget:

```
class PyDMLabel(QLabel, PyDMWidget):
    class DisplayFormat:
        DEFAULT = 0
        STRING = 1
        DECIMAL = 2
        EXPONENTIAL = 3
        HEX = 4
        BINARY = 5

    Q_ENUMS(DisplayFormat)

    """
    A QLabel with support for Channels and more from PyDM

    Parameters
    ----------
    parent : QWidget
        The parent widget for the Label
    init_channel : str, optional
        The channel to be used by the widget.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None, init_channel=None):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        PyDMWidget.__init__(self, init_channel=init_channel)

        self.setTextFormat(Qt.PlainText)
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.setText("PyDMLabel")
        self._display_format_type = PyDMLabel.DisplayFormat.DEFAULT

    @pyqtProperty(DisplayFormat)
    def displayFormat(self):
        return self._display_format_type

    @displayFormat.setter
    def displayFormat(self, new_type):
        if self._display_format_type != new_type:
            self._display_format_type = new_type
```

What is the correct way to deal with `Q_ENUMS` and PyQt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Qt (Designer) to see an enum, PyQt has to add it to the [meta-object](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html) of the custom class. So it could never be referred to by Qt as `DisplayFormat::STRING`.

In Qt, enums declared in the class scope expose their constants as members of the class. So for example, the [QComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) class defines an [InsertPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#InsertPolicy-enum) enum, and the constants can be referred to like this: `QComboBox::InsertAtTop`. So in that respect, the behaviour of PyQt `Q_ENUMS` in Qt Designer plugins is exactly as expected, since the ui file shows `PyDMLabel::STRING`.

However, getting fully equivalent behaviour in Python code requires some extra work. The nearest I could come up with is this:

```
class DisplayFormat:
    DEFAULT = 0
    STRING = 1
    DECIMAL = 2
    EXPONENTIAL = 3
    HEX = 4
    BINARY = 5

class PyDMLabel(QLabel, PyDMWidget, DisplayFormat):
    DisplayFormat = DisplayFormat

    Q_ENUMS(DisplayFormat)
```

This will *still* result in Qt Designer using `PyDMLabel::STRING` (as expected). But Python code can now access the constants in any of these ways:

```
PyDMLabel.STRING
PyDMLabel.DisplayFormat.STRING
DisplayFormat.STRING
```

And in fact, if you don't mind losing the second of these options, you could simplify things even further to this:

```
class DisplayFormat:
    DEFAULT = 0
    ...    

class PyDMLabel(QLabel, PyDMWidget, DisplayFormat):    
    Q_ENUMS(DisplayFormat)
```

Comment: Thank you @ekhumoro! With your suggestion I was able to get it to work.
Do you know if it would be possible to create dynamic enums using the same concept?

Comment: @hhslepicka. I'm not exactly sure. I think PyQt does some meta-class hackery to get `Q_ENUMS` to work, which is why it needs to be defined in the class scope. But I don't know whether there's any way around that.

Comment: thank you again. I will try to investigate also how to make something on the same lines as Qt for the general enums also and if I find something I will come back here to post.

Comment: I'm guessing this would also work with an actual Python enumeration?